# Rich text editor link to media not working

Tags: sitecore

I have inserted media item using rich text editor and link looks like below

```
<img alt="" src="media/8AC956DF5182489F9F8D8C98CC06BE6E.ashx" width="560" height="193" />
```

the image renders well on sitecore page edit/preview mode. but it does not render on actual website. when I inspect it looks like below in the browser

```
<img alt="" src="media/8AC956DF5182489F9F8D8C98CC06BE6E.ashx" width="560" height="193">
```

Please help.

Comment: What's your setting of `Media.MediaLinkPrefix`? Check in `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`, it should be empty by default.

Comment: it is <setting name="Media.MediaLinkPrefix" value="media"/>

Comment: I'm sure you checked this but can you double check that the image already in web database.

Comment: yes.. image is present in web database

Comment: Post the code how you are rendering the rich text field on the front end.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the Media.MediaLinkPrefix value "media"

Use
`<setting name="Media.MediaLinkPrefix" value=""/>` (for the default value)
"that is ~/media" or "-/media depend on the Sitecore version"

or use

`<setting name="Media.MediaLinkPrefix" value="-/media" />`

See also https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/723979 for Sitecore version below 8.1

Comment: You can actually use anything you like for MediaLinkPrefix, it does not _have to_ be the default Sitecore values, you just need to ensure it is unique.

Comment: Yep you can change it, Then also change the custom Handlers handler trigger. like the kb article say.

Comment: And I guess use a first a /

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this:

```
<img alt="" src="~/media/8AC956DF5182489F9F8D8C98CC06BE6E.ashx" width="560" height="193" />
```

see the change in the beginning of the src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue before, but then I found that it was my mistake (not Sitecore issue because you're able to see the images properly in page editor) because I was sending the HTML contents of rich text field to frontend directly, sure here it won't work because I'm not calling URL which will be the Base root of the images or any media src attribute (coz it include relative URL), so I've just changed my code while I'm rendering to frontend to replace all relative URL's to be absolute like this:

```
WebUtility.HtmlDecode(item.Fields["field_name"].Value.Replace("-/media/", Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + '/' + "~/media/"));
```

but in your case if your src looks like this `src="media/8AC956DF5182489F9F8D8C98CC06BE6E.ashx"` so you can use the code:

```
WebUtility.HtmlDecode(item.Fields["field_name"].Value.Replace("media/", Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + '/' + "~/media/"));
```

**Note:** Sitecore Rich text editor is already rendering decoded HTML and I'm using `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` just for double check.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably with how you are rendering the richtext editor field on the frontend. For whatever reason it looks like the LinkProvider in sitecore is being skipped. The LinkProvider is what would convert what you see in the FrontEnd to a working and friendly link.

It is working in Page Editor because it is design to work with the link in that format.

Check to see that you are not directly accessing the RichText value and that you are using the rendering pipeline.